# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)")

Tags: python, mysql

I'm getting the following error when running my python script on a 2008 vm
running mysql server 5.6
using ajax

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypythonjob.py", line 22, in <module>
    db = mdb.connect('localhost', 'website','servername', 'website')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10055)")
```

I can watch in resource monitor as the cpu climbs to 100% after about 75 seconds at that point mysql.exe has 30 threads and python.exe has 6 threads
the error kicks out and python.exe is terminated and mysql server is un reachable for about 2mins then it comes back on line.

```
import os, datetime, pymssql , time, subprocess
import MySQLdb as mdb
today = datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
sixmonth = today - datetime.timedelta(days=180)
db = mdb.connect('localhost', 'website','server', 'website')  #values changed for post
cursor = db.cursor()
sql2 = "select 1column from mytable where 4column like '"+str(today)+"'"   #values changed for post (query produces 1100 rows)
cursor.execute(sql2)
data2 = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.close()
db.close()  
for row2 in data2:
    db = pymssql.connect(host="sqldb",user="username", password="pwd", database="somedatabase")  #values changed for post
    cursor = db.cursor()
    sql3 = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; select col1,col2,col3 from tbl where col1 like '%somedata%' and col3 < '"+str(sixmonth)+"' and col2 ='data'"     #values changed for post
    cursor.execute(sql3)
    data3 = cursor.fetchall()
    db.commit()
    cursor.close()
    db.close()
    for row3 in data3:
        db = mdb.connect('localhost', 'website','server', 'website')
        cursor = db.cursor()
        sql4 = "update mytable set 2column ='"+str(row3[2])+"', 3column ='"+str(row3[1])+"' where 4column like '"+str(today)+"' and 1column like '"+str(row3[0])+"'"      #values changed for post (seems to finish the update properly at 575 rows)
        cursor.execute(sql4)
        data4 = cursor.fetchall()
        db.commit()
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
```

Resolution attempts 
ran the code with a small 10 row of the starting data vs 1100
checked to make sure i'm closing connections and db's when i'm done with them 
i check the mysql log file there is nothing
changed the setting max_allowed_packet in my.ini to 32mg then 500mg and finally commented out

thanks for looking

added note:
If i remove SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED; from the second query it seems to continue to run. I let it go for 5 mins and the count stopped at 575 updated and held there.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue, i was not passing the variable properly from the first query to the second so it was killing the server with results then passing that bloating line count into the update.